# Material UI Tabs: Nested tabs results in an invalid value error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tabs

Having nested tabs results in the following error in the console:

> MUI: The `value` provided to the Tabs component is invalid.
> The Tab with this `value` ("0") is not part of the document layout. Make sure the tab item is present in the document or that it's not `display: none`.

In the [Basic tabs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/#basic-tabs) example in the docs, the `TabPanel` component has the following check: `value === index`. Including this in my `TabPanel` fixes this issue, however I need the child components to stay mounted and just be hidden. Having this check causes the tab content to be unmounted.

[CodeSandbox example of the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-marco-2m9lrl?file=/src/TabPage1.tsx)

[Similar issue on Material UI's GitHub](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32749)